# using fft in processing

Tags: java, processing, fft, visualizer

I was wondering if someone could help me. I am currently working on a project using processing to use FFT for an aesthetics project. What I wanna do is allow the user to import a song, and have the fft act as a visualizer to react and display different colors based on the song. The problem I am having is I can not get the fft itself to work. How can I get processing to recognize the fft?

Here is the fft code I'm using.

```
    fft = new FFT(song.bufferSize(), song.sampleRate());

   //DRAW FFT
  fft.forward(song.mix);
  colorMode(HSB, 255);


  void wavewave() {
  float spread = map(450, 0, width, 1, 21.5);
  float x = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < song.sampleRate() && x < width; i += spread)
  {
    x = i/spread;
    stroke(map(fft.getFreq(i), 0, 256, 0, 360) * 2, //Hue
    255, //Saturation
    255); //Brightness
    line(x, 512, x, 512 - fft.getFreq(i) * 4);
  }
  //map(value, minimum1, maximum1, minimum2, maximum2);

  x = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < song.sampleRate() && x < width; i += spread)
  {
    x = i/spread;
    stroke(map(fft.getFreq(i), 0, 256, 0, 360) * 2, //Hue
    255, //Saturation
    255); //Brightness
    line(x, 512, x, 512 + fft.getFreq(i) * 4);
  }
  }
```

I keep getting unidentified token fft, as the error

```
 import ddf.minim.spi.*;
 import ddf.minim.signals.*;
 import ddf.minim.*;
 import ddf.minim.analysis.*;
 import ddf.minim.ugens.*;
 import ddf.minim.effects.*;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FilenameFilter;


    color waveColor;
    int waveIncr = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int songCounter = 0;
    int fadeLevel = 10;


    float buttonX;
    float buttonY;
    float buttonW;
    float buttonH;

    Minim minim;
    AudioPlayer player;
    FFT fft;
    ArrayList<Songs> s;
    int k;

    String filename;

    boolean isSelected = false;

    void setup() {

      s = new ArrayList();

      textSize(24);

      frame.setResizable(false);

      background(255);

      size(600, 600);

      fill(0);
      stroke(0);
      noFill();

      buttonW = 200;
      buttonH = 50;
      buttonX = width - width/2 - buttonW/2;
      buttonY = height/2 - buttonH/2;

      // Minim stuff
      minim = new Minim(this);
    }

    void draw() {

      background(255);
      fill(0);

      rectMode(CORNER);

      rect(buttonX, buttonY, buttonW, buttonH);

      fill(255);

      textAlign(LEFT);
      text("Import File", buttonX+35, buttonY+30);

      if (isSelected) {
       // s.get(k).waveform();
        s.get(k).wavewave();
      }
    }

    void mouseClicked() {
      if (mouseX>buttonX && mouseX < buttonX+buttonW && mouseY > buttonY && mouseY < buttonY+buttonH) {
        selectInput("Import music file", "fileSelected");
      }
    }

    /* Taken from Processing.org */
    void fileSelected(File selection) {
      if (selection == null) {
        println("Window was closed or user hit cancel");
      } 
      else {
        filename = selection.getAbsolutePath();
        s.add(new Songs(player, filename, "Filename"));
        isSelected = true;
      }
    }

    // stop minim and the player.
    void stop() {
      player.close();
      minim.stop();
      super.stop();
    }

    class Songs {
      AudioPlayer song; 
      String directory;
      String songName;
      Songs(AudioPlayer song, String directory, String songName) {

        song=minim.loadFile(directory);    

        this.song=song;
        this.songName=songName;
        song.play();
      }



        fft = new FFT(song.bufferSize(), song.sampleRate());

       //DRAW FFT
      fft.forward(song.mix);
      colorMode(HSB, 255);


      void wavewave() {
      float spread = map(450, 0, width, 1, 21.5);
      float x = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < song.sampleRate() && x < width; i += spread)
      {
        x = i/spread;
        stroke(map(fft.getFreq(i), 0, 256, 0, 360) * 2, //Hue
        255, //Saturation
        255); //Brightness
        line(x, 512, x, 512 - fft.getFreq(i) * 4);
      }
      //map(value, minimum1, maximum1, minimum2, maximum2);

      x = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < song.sampleRate() && x < width; i += spread)
      {
        x = i/spread;
        stroke(map(fft.getFreq(i), 0, 256, 0, 360) * 2, //Hue
        255, //Saturation
        255); //Brightness
        line(x, 512, x, 512 + fft.getFreq(i) * 4);
      }
      }


    }
```

Comment: Try to reduce your code to a minimal working example, and please add a tag with the language you are using.

Comment: There's nothing really to reduce it to. The only thing on the code that does not work is the fft. As for the tag it is already it says processing.

Comment: By minimal I mean removing all drawings, mouse clicks, file loading, etc. leaving only the FFT call you are having problems with, with some fake data to make the call. And by language tag I meant Java or whatever language you are using, it would help people to find the question.

Comment: Oh ok misunderstood your first comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have some syntax errors. Here's your code moved about a bit:

```
import ddf.minim.spi.*;
import ddf.minim.signals.*;
import ddf.minim.*;
import ddf.minim.analysis.*;
import ddf.minim.ugens.*;
import ddf.minim.effects.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;


color waveColor;
int waveIncr = 0;
int counter = 0;
int songCounter = 0;
int fadeLevel = 10;


float buttonX;
float buttonY;
float buttonW;
float buttonH;

Minim minim;
AudioPlayer player;
FFT fft;
ArrayList<Songs> s;
int k;

String filename;

boolean isSelected = false;

void setup() {

  s = new ArrayList();

  textSize(24);

  frame.setResizable(false);

  background(255);

  size(600, 600);

  fill(0);
  stroke(0);
  noFill();

  buttonW = 200;
  buttonH = 50;
  buttonX = width - width/2 - buttonW/2;
  buttonY = height/2 - buttonH/2;

  // Minim stuff
  minim = new Minim(this);
}

void draw() {

  background(255);
  fill(0);

  rectMode(CORNER);

  rect(buttonX, buttonY, buttonW, buttonH);

  fill(255);

  textAlign(LEFT);
  text("Import File", buttonX+35, buttonY+30);

  if (isSelected) {
    // s.get(k).waveform();
    s.get(k).wavewave();
  }
}

void mouseClicked() {
  if (mouseX>buttonX && mouseX < buttonX+buttonW && mouseY > buttonY && mouseY < buttonY+buttonH) {
    selectInput("Import music file", "fileSelected");
  }
}

/* Taken from Processing.org */
void fileSelected(File selection) {
  if (selection == null) {
    println("Window was closed or user hit cancel");
  } 
  else {
    filename = selection.getAbsolutePath();
    s.add(new Songs(player, filename, "Filename"));
    isSelected = true;
  }
}

// stop minim and the player.
void stop() {
  player.close();
  minim.stop();
  super.stop();
}

class Songs {
  AudioPlayer song; 
  String directory;
  String songName;
  Songs(AudioPlayer song, String directory, String songName) {

    song=minim.loadFile(directory);    

    this.song=song;
    this.songName=songName;
    song.play();


    fft = new FFT(song.bufferSize(), song.sampleRate());
  }

  void wavewave() {
    //DRAW FFT
    fft.forward(song.mix);
    colorMode(HSB, 255);

    float spread = map(450, 0, width, 1, 21.5);
    float x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < song.sampleRate() && x < width; i += spread)
    {
      x = i/spread;
      stroke(map(fft.getFreq(i), 0, 256, 0, 360) * 2, //Hue
      255, //Saturation
      255); //Brightness
      line(x, 512, x, 512 - fft.getFreq(i) * 4);
    }
    //map(value, minimum1, maximum1, minimum2, maximum2);

    x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < song.sampleRate() && x < width; i += spread)
    {
      x = i/spread;
      stroke(map(fft.getFreq(i), 0, 256, 0, 360) * 2, //Hue
      255, //Saturation
      255); //Brightness
      line(x, 512, x, 512 + fft.getFreq(i) * 4);
    }
  }
}
```

You should try the [PDE X](http://www.mkmoharana.com/2013/09/announcing-pde-x.html) mode, might help you with errors in the future, plus it's awesome!

Comment: Will do, and I'm actually thinking of adding a little more to the code, because this is actually a project for my german class based on aesthetics, and I really want it to interact more with the music. Do you have any ideas on what could be added?

Comment: I'm guessing aesthetics are more important. If so, perhaps look into gestalt principles and early experimental films that explore the connection between image and sound(see [Norman McLaren](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=norman+mclaren&oq=norman+mclaren&aqs=chrome..69i57.5462j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=norman+mclaren&tbm=vid), [John Whitney](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=john+whitney&oq=john+whitney&aqs=chrome..69i57.3074j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=john+whitney&tbm=vid) and others). HTH

Comment: Regarding sound, to get good visual results, you will need to process the FFT data quite a bit since ATM you're only dealing with the raw results, not taking into account perceptual weighting for example. Start with very simple tests/sketches and begin by looking at the fft averaging and beat detection samples. Use simple audio at the start and minimal graphics until you get the hang of creating a meaningful link between what you see and what you hear. You can always improve and do more complex things later. Also simple graphics will help the brain focus more on sound and make the links itself